# How to use express.js with mysql and express-myconnection?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am using Express 4.9.0 and express-generator. Executed this command:

`express --hbs projectname`

Installed following modules with NPM:

- mysql
- express-myconnection

I want to make todo application. I have created separate file under `routes/todo.js` and created get/post routes for creating todos in that file using `router.get` and `router.post`.

i have following code in app.js:

```
// mysql connection
var connection = require('express-myconnection');
var mysql = require('mysql');

app.use(
    connection(mysql, {
        host : config.db.host,
        user : config.db.user,
        password : config.db.password,
        database : config.db.database,
        debug : false //set true if you wanna see debug logger
    }, 'request')
);
// end of mysql connection
```

Where should i place mysql config and connection code? Inside `todo.js`? I still don't get concept of organisation file structure and where to place database queries.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you eventually found the answer, but I thought it might help out others who accidentally stumbled on your question:

After you've setup like mentioned above, you can call the connection from the request object using the getConnection method like this:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) { 
    req.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        connection.query('select * from table_name', function(err, rows, fields){
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            } else {
                res.jsonp(rows);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

This should print out a json with the content of your table all nice an pretty.
Hope this comes in handy.